# Get entities by multiple ids in N:N relation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Given entities:
Team, User. Relation between those is N:N.

Question:
How do I find users which belong to specified teams (with given list of ids).

PS.
I found how to do with single team, but have no clue how to deal with the list of teams?

```cs
var team_id = ...
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("user");

// setting up relation between teams and users
Relationship rel = new Relationship();
rel.SchemaName = "new_teams_users";

RelationshipQueryCollection relatedEntity = new RelationshipQueryCollection();
relatedEntity.Add(rel, query);

RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
request.RelatedEntitiesQuery = relatedEntity;
request.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new string[] {"id"});

request.Target = new EntityReference { Id = team_id, LogicalName = "new_team" };

// Results: List of users by team id.
RetrieveResponse response = (RetrieveResponse)CrmService.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Are you querying standard CRM "user" and "team" entites, or custom ones? Schema name in your example has `new_` prefix which indicates custom relationship. Also, there is no `user` entity in crm. Users are stored in entity named `systemuser`. 'user' is just display name.

Comment: It was just an example. Spelling doesn't have much sense. In the real life we use standard entity ("product") and custom entity ("new_facility"). Relation should be set between products and facilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QueryExpression build on intersect entity will help you. As example i used product and competitor N:N relationship

```cs
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression()
{
    EntityName = "competitorproduct",  //this name can be get from N:N rel properties (Relationship form, Relationship Entity Name field)
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
};

qe.Criteria.AddCondition(
    "competitorid", 
    ConditionOperator.In, 
    new object[] { "GUID1", "GUID2"});

//Below is optional - if you need some details of entity, add LinkEntity object. This example adds all fields from product entity
LinkEntity lePorduct = new LinkEntity("competitorproduct", "product", "productid", "productid", JoinOperator.Inner);
lePorduct.Columns = new ColumnSet(true);
qe.LinkEntities.Add(lePorduct);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would make your primary entity the intersection entity so in your example it would be "TeamMembership" the criteria would then be set against the attribute "SystemUserId".

To get more information on the team you need to add the team entity as a linked entity to your query like this

```
 LinkEntity TeamLink = new LinkEntity();
            TeamLink .EntityAlias = "TeamLink ";
            TeamLink .JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner;
            TeamLink .LinkFromEntityName = "teammembership";
            TeamLink .LinkFromAttributeName = "teamid";
            TeamLink .LinkToEntityName = "team";
            TeamLink .LinkToAttributeName = "teamid";
```

You can then bring back what ever columns you want and get the data out.

Comment: Any more information other than it not working? Does it come up with an error or are you just not getting any data? That should work a I have done similar queries with products

Comment: I thought it wouldn't work because none of the entities has "teamid" attribute. But I see your point with intersection entity. So how do I create "teammembership" intersection entity?